# Contour Integration Limitations?

Tags: contour-integration

So, I'm trying to evaluate the following integral by complex contour integration ONLY:

$$\int_0^\infty{\frac{x^\alpha}{x(x+1)}} dx$$ where alpha is real and not an integer.

Obviously, we need to use a key-hole contour to avoid the resulting branch cut, and I can carry out the analysis.  However, I am finding that, if alpha > 1, then the contour for R going from 0 to $2\pi$ becomes undefined (it basically blows up; I'm using an inequality arguement).  Is this correct, or can it actually be evaluated for alpha > 1?  Also, what about alpha < 0?

Please do not solve this out fully; I have already done so.  here is my result:

$$\int_0^\infty{\frac{x^\alpha}{x(x+1)}} dx=\frac{2\pi ie^{i\alpha\pi}}{e^{i2\pi\alpha}-1}$$ which gives me correct results.

Comment: The integral is finite only for $0 < \alpha < 1$. For $\alpha \leqslant 0$, you have a non-integrable singularity in $0$, and for $\alpha \geqslant 1$, it decays too slowly. Note that you can simplify your result to $$\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi\alpha}.$$

Comment: All integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{(1+x^m)^p}dx$ are solved by substituting $t=\dfrac1{(1+x^m)^p}$, and then recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, followed by employing Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties). In this case, $n=a-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\alpha} \over x\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}.\qquad
    0 < \alpha < 1}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\alpha} \over x\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x}
> =2\pi\ic\ \verts{-1}^{\alpha - 1}\ \expo{\ic\pi\pars{\alpha - 1}}
> -\int_{\infty}^{0}{x^{\alpha}\expo{2\pi\pars{\alpha - 1}\ic} \over x\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#44f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\alpha} \over x\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x}
=-2\pi\ic\,
{\expo{\ic\pi\alpha} \over 1 - \expo{2\pi\alpha\ic}}
=\pi\,{2\ic \over \expo{\ic\pi\alpha} - \expo{-\ic\pi\alpha}}
=\color{#44f}{\large{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi\alpha}}}
\end{align}

[image]